# Configure ios app : Programaticall configuration of ios apps for social login rather than using info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus, facebook-ios-sdk, linkedin-ios-sdk

There is any way to set app Id,URL schema properties  for social login like Facebook ,LinkedIn, google plus in ios app ..
instead of using info.plist.

Is it possible to customize it programmatically using swift.?
how we can dynamically set App iD and URL schema in the case of Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

```
    enter code here
FBSDKSettings.setAppID("xxxxxxxxxxx")
FBSDKSettings.setDisplayName("App Name");
```

This code will help you to set App Id and Display name for Facebook app in iOS .